# Google DataTable - Update cell and display

Tags: google-visualization, google-datatable

I'm having trouble updating a cell in Google DataTable and having the display reflect the change. Right now, my solution is to redraw the table but it messes up the page scrolling and where the user was at in the table.

Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used the setCell function? The following code below provides a button to change one of the names in the table. If a user clicks on a row to highlight it, it does not change the scroll position or which row is highlighted.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["table"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      var table;
      var data;

      function drawTable() {
        data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true],
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true],
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true],
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }

      function changeCell() {
          data.setCell(1, 0, 'Changed Name');
          table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
    <button onclick="changeCell()">Change</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That's exactly what I'm doing.